# Ubuntu GNOME + OpenVPN - DNS Leaks. Howto configure?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, openvpn, ubuntu-gnome

I'd like my DNS queries to not be used to [advertise/track](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/03/how-isps-can-sell-your-web-history-and-how-to-stop-them/) me.

I'm using [this site](https://www.dnsleaktest.com) to check for leaks.

The client is Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and the server is configured like [this](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install).

The VPN works.  Through the GUI, it leaks DNS.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
# settings -> network-> + (lower left) -> VPN -> Import from file...
```

There is a [work-around for the leaks](https://askubuntu.com/a/833970/268145), but it [doesn't work from network manager](https://serverfault.com/questions/647231/getting-cannot-ioctl-tunsetiff-tun-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-con).

Ubuntu GNOME's tools also can't configure to automatically connect to VPN's w/o running `nm-connection-editor` and configuring each WiFi connection.

It seems like this should be set-and-forget.  How to do that?

Is there a way to automatically connect the VPN when network connections happen?

Essentially this command:  `sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn`

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I edited `/etc/default/openvpn` and uncommmented this line:  `AUTOSTART="all"`

Then copied the client.ovpn file to `/etc/openvpn/client.conf`.

After boot, the network works and no DNS leaks.  If I switch the WiFi connection, the WiFi connects, but OpenVPN doesn't appear to reconnect (browsers don't work).

I can get OpenVPN to reconnect with this command:

`sudo service openvpn restart`

So, that get's me: works on boot and doesn't leak.

It's not set-and-forget because of having to restart openvpn service, but at least it's fail fast.

Any suggestions?