# Preventing DNS Leak using OpenVPN for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

I recently bought a VPN service and have been playing around with the settings and functions but found that I was still leaking my IP address to some sites.

Akamai Technologies kept serving up websites close to my Geolocation meaning that it knew where my IP address originated.

Turns out it was an issue with my ISP provider. I have been looking into fixing the DNS leak using DNSCrypt but the only guide I could find is for Windows and Mac machines.

I currently use OpenVPN and found this related (and unanswered) question in Ask Ubuntu: [How do I fix a DNS leak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607895/how-do-i-fix-a-dns-leak)

That points to this guide: http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html

But it does not say what the name of the .ovpn file is. I searched for the .ovpn file on my system but couldn't find anything with that extension.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If there is an .ovpn file for your connection it's your .ovpn file, you created it. The author of the article can't know what you named it.

Comment: I haven't created an .ovpn file. The guide also mentioned that it would update the /etc/resolv.conf folder automatically. My machine currently does not have a /etc/resolv.conf folder. Not too sure how to proceed. I am running OpenVPN.

Comment: Are you routing all traffic through this VPN, or only some of the traffic? You also need to be careful as anyone else on the VPN could tunnel back into your machine, so you should set up appropriate firewall measures. Does the VPN provider send DNS info? It should be sending suggested addresses for DNS when your computer requests an IP on that network, from DHCP.

Comment: I don't know how you created your client side OpenVPN profile but every tutorial  I've used gives instructions for creating the .ovpn file. It's basically just the client config file with all the .crt and key files appended. Check out one of the digitalocean tutorials.

Comment: Hi @dobey. I am routing everything through the VPN (as far as I can tell). I haven't looked into firewall settings but so far everything seems to be okay (no viruses as far as I can tell). I don't know if the VPN provider sends DNS info... after installing openVPN I did it in such a way that it asked for my VPN providers login details. Sometimes it requires me to input the password that I can change on the VPN providers website. How do I check if my VPN provider sends DNS info? Thanks again for the help with this!

Comment: To set up my vpn I used the following commands: `sudo apt-get install curl network-manager-openvpn-gnome` `wget https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/installer/pia-nm.sh` `sudo bash pia-nm.sh`. I was prompted for some login details and other setup parameters.

Comment: @OrganicMarble NetworkManager doesn't use standard OpenVPN config files to manage VPN connections.

Comment: I was looking for  a low impact VPN service. I managed to fix the DNS leak by finding the DNS servers my VPN provided. I simply updated my DNS connection and this fixed the DNS leak.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DNS leak with 17.x or 18.04 as indicated by checking on 
[www.browserleaks.com](http://www.browserleaks.com) or [dnsleaktest.com](http://www.dnsleaktest.com), For 16.04 LTS, see the link below.

1. Shut off your VPN connection
2. Attempt to undo any .conf file edits you've wasted time already making.  If you've been trying a lot of various suggestions, your best good chance might be to do a fresh install and ensure you've also installed networkmanager-openvpn-gnome as Ubuntu does not have VPN config importing provided by default.
3. Install dnsmasq

   `sudo apt update
    sudo apt install dnsmasq`
4. Disable resolved

   `systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
    systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service`
5. Remove /etc/resolv.conf and create a new one:

   `rm /etc/resolv.conf
    nano /etc/resolv.conf`
6. Enter into your empty .conf file:

   `nameserver 127.0.0.1`         that's all!
7. save and exit out of your new resolv.conf file.
8. Edit your NetworkManager.conf file

`nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

and add the following:

```
`dns=dnsmasq`
```

beneath the lines, [main] and plugins=ifupdown, keyfile

this is what your edited file should look like

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown, keyfile
dns=dnsmasq
```

save and exit.

9.Back out of the terminal, and reboot the system and check your dnsleak test site for results.

With thanks to [Anonymous VPN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYW4aJntC8s) whose solutions for Leaks on Ubuntu/Network Manager seem well researched and successful.  THEY WORK and when no other solutions worked for me, these did.  The above shown solution works for Ubuntu [17.x and 18.04 LTS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYW4aJntC8s).  For [16.04 LTS, [see his other solution]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFbvrIQpeaQ)5